# Powershell - SQL Server - connectionstring in loop for multiple Instances

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell

Thisis part of a bigger script which finds *DatabaseFiles* on a SQL Server machine (multiple instances).

Following should just return all files for 3 instances.

The server is called `V3000801` and there is one default instance + 2 named instances on there. It's ok with me if either default or named doesn't work I'll work around this alone (most likely create a flag and do default with another connection string).

`$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` just returns -1 which does not make any sense for me.

Thanks for the help

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $instances.Length;$i++){
  $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
  $Server= "V3000801\"+$instances[$i];
  $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $server ; Database = master; Integrated Security = sspi;trusted_connection=true";
  $sqlQuery="SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files;";

  Write-Host $SqlConnection.ConnectionString;

  $SqlConnection.Open();
  $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
  $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlQuery;
  $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;
  $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  $SqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `-1` [makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514855/503046) when you consider what `ExecuteNonQuery()` does. It [returns the number of rows affected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) or `-1` in case of `set nocount on` or non-updating queries.

As per documentation,

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. ... For
>   all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback
>   occurs, the return value is also -1.

Try `.ExecuteReader()` instead.